# How to access instance member variables via std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I don't know why I can't find this somewhere online, but how can I access `class instance member variables` via a `shared_ptr?` The ways I've tried are commented out in the code below. They've both result in a `segmentation fault`.

I assume I could access the member variables by getting a `raw pointer` from the `shared_ptr` but I'd rather avoid that as it's not clean and negates the value of the `shared_ptr` What's a safe way to access these member variables?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Test{
public:
  int x;
  Test() : x(5){}
};

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Test> f;
 // the following lines both produce seg faults
 //  std::cout << (*f).x << std::endl;
 //  std::cout << f->x << std::endl;

    }
```

Comment: `f->x` is correct but `f` isn't managing a pointer when you try accessing it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem lies on the line `std::shared_ptr<Test> f;`.  That line is similar to `Test* f;`; you declare a pointer to a `Test`, but you've not created a `Test` object for it to point to.  You need to use

```
std::shared_ptr<Test> f(std::make_shared<Test>());
```

Then you can access members with `f->x` or `(*f).x` the same as you would a raw pointer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use:

```
std::shared_ptr<Test> f = std::make_shared<Test>();
```

Then you can access `f->x`. If you have C++11, you can remove some redundancy with the `auto` keyword and use:

```
auto f = std::make_shared<Test>();
```

> Note that as a general rule, std::make_shared() is "better" than using `new` directly. `make_shared` allocates an instance of Test and the reference count needed for the shared_ptr in one memory allocation; using `new` means there will be two memory allocations--one for the new Test instance and one for the reference count used inside the `shared_ptr`. As with any generalization, there are times when `make_shared` will not work (e.g., when the class uses a custom allocator), but for this simple case, I think using make_shared is more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate shared data. Something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Test> f( new Test());
```

Comment: This is a different solution than the current top answer.  Is it better?

Comment: No it is the same. make_shared is added in C++11 standard as a helper for instantiating shared data.

Comment: @DrewDormann Well, at least this one mentions that the shared data has to be initialized. The answer you refer to doesn't explain anything.

Comment: As a general rule, std::make_shared<Test>() is "better." It allocates an instance of Test and the reference count needed for the shared_ptr in one memory allocation. As with any generalization, there are times when make_shared will not work (e.g., when the class uses a custom allocator), but for this simple case, I think using make_shared is more helpful.